# API_ENDPOINT in Parse

Tags: codenameone

I've been trying to connect to Parse using my Codename One but it gives me this message: [EDT] 0:0:12,74 - [parse4cn1] Request failed.

So I don't know if it's a problem with the API_ENDPOINT or what, so this is what I did: `Parse.initialize("https://parseapi.back4app.com/", "my_app_id", "my_client_id");`

Is there anything I did wrong that I need to change?

This is my network monitor:

[image: network monitor][image: network monitor]

Comment: Check the network monitor in the simulator to get more information about the failed request.  You should be able to see the request and response headers, and any response body sent.

Comment: I just updated it now with my network monitor, I have not used it before, please help me through it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution just now, my mistake was instead of having the API_ENDPOINT as:
`https://parseapi.back4app.com/`, have it as `https://parseapi.back4app.com` without the slash.